# How to paste 2x2 contingency table into rstudio?

Tags: r, datatable

Is there a way to directly import a 2x2 contingency table from MS Excel into R? I tried read.table, it didn't work. Creating 2x2 table in R takes steps like matrix(), colname () etc. I am looking to bring already existing 2x2 table into R and do further stats. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Sample 2x2 Table:

[Sample 2x2 Table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3HhU.png)

Comment: 'It didn't work' isn't very helpful. What about it didn't work? The easiest thing would be to save it as a .csv file and then just do ``read.table("dat.csv", sep=",")``.

Comment: Try `readxl::read_excel`.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: Getting following error.
"X11 module cannot be loaded"

Any idea about it?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you want a one-liner to get the table, this will do it `tbl <- matrix(c(44, 300, 20, 902), 2, 2, dimnames=list(Exposed=c("Exposed", "Not Exposed"), Sick=c("Sick", "Not sick")))`.

Comment: Using MacOS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The function below automates the several steps needed to read from an Excel file and set the row names.

It assumes that it's

- a two way contingency table;
- in sheet 1.

If this is not true, change the function's defaults and pass other arguments in the dots argument.

```
read_contingency_excel <- function(path, col_names = TRUE, 
                                   col_types = c("text", "numeric", "numeric"),
                                   ...){
  tbl <- readxl::read_excel(path, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types, ...)
  tbl <- as.data.frame(tbl)
  row.names(tbl) <- tbl[[1]]
  tbl[[1]] <- NULL
  tbl
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Getting following error;
"X11 module cannot be loaded".